# Javascript - how to use the same onkeydown event to call different functions on different occasions

Tags: javascript, call, addeventlistener, onkeydown

I am trying to make a simple quizz with random questions.
After typing in the answer, the user can press the Enter key to check whether his answer is correct or wrong. In that moment the textbox will be hidden.

I would like the user to be able to press the Enter key again to proceed to the next question. But how can I do that, since I already have a function being called with that key?

This is what I am working with:

```js
    var country = ["Italy", "Spain", "Portugal", "France"];
    var capital = ["rome", "madrid", "lisbon", "paris"];
    var random001 = Math.floor(Math.random() * country.length);

    document.getElementById("country").innerHTML = country[random001];

    function submit001() {
        var b = input001.value.toLowerCase();
        var text;
        switch (true) {
            case random001 == 0 && b == capital[0]:
            case random001 == 1 && b == capital[1]:
            case random001 == 2 && b == capital[2]:
            case random001 == 3 && b == capital[3]:
                text = "Correct!";
                hideAndShowDIV();
                break;
            default:
                text = input001.value.bold() + " is not correct!";
                document.getElementById("input001").value = "";
        }
        document.getElementById("answer001").innerHTML = text;
    }

    function hideAndShowDIV() {
        var x = document.getElementById("userInput");
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    function goToNextQuestion() {
        random001 = Math.floor(Math.random() * country.length);
        document.getElementById("country").innerHTML = country[random001];
        hideAndShowDIV()
        document.getElementById("input001").focus();
    }
```

```html
    <p id="message001">What is the capital of <text id="country"></text>?</p>
    <div id="userInput" style="display:block">
        <input type="text" id="input001" autofocus onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) submit001();">
    </div>
    <p id="answer001"></p>
```

The `function goToNextQuestion()` is what I want to call with the Enter key.

Comment: Are you talking about doing this purely from a "How would you do it?" point of view or are you actually planning on releasing this to users?  If it's "for real", I'd STRONGLY recommend not using this approach, due to a number of major user experience issues.

Comment: @talemyn I was thinking about having it online, for real. What are those user experience issues you are talking about?

Comment: @MikeMichaels For one, it's generally not a great plan to have the same action perform situational responses. Users might not always be able to tell why the same action leads to a different result.

Comment: @talemyn I understand. But how could I accomplish that anyway? Purely from a "How would you do it?" perspective...

Comment: @MikeMichaels - they mostly issues around "expected behavior".  Browsers tend to let the user move between fields using the `Tab` and `Shift+Tab` keys, and the `Enter` key's functionality is somewhat inconsistent.  So first off, you'd be duplicating functionality that is already provided by other keys, plus adding it to a key that (sometimes) has a different behavior.  In addition, it gets even more confusing by adding a second behavior that changes based on a state that is not obvious to a user (i.e., "Has 'Enter' been pressed already?").  Help text **might** help, but users often skip that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution would be to add an extra line in the function `submit001`, before any of the code it already has:

```
if (document.getElementById("answer001").textContent === "Correct") {
    goToNextQuestion();
}
```

And in the function `gotoNextQuestion` you should then make sure to clear that text content (remove "Correct").

But be aware the the keydown event does not trigger on the `input` element when you hide it, so you should listen to that event on the document.

Better still would be to use a variable for that state, instead of depending on what is in the HTML document.

Here is an implementation that uses `addEventListener` instead of having JS code inside your HTML tags. Note how it listens on the document level. Also better to use the event `key` property and not `keyCode`.

A new variable `execOnEnter` defines which function to execute depending on the state of the "game". It is changed in the code to either `submit001` or `goToNextQuestion`:

```js
var country = ["Italy", "Spain", "Portugal", "France"];
var capital = ["rome", "madrid", "lisbon", "paris"];
var random001 = Math.floor(Math.random() * country.length);

document.getElementById("country").textContent = country[random001];

var execOnEnter = submit001;
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.key !== "Enter") return;
    execOnEnter();
});

function submit001() {
    var b = input001.value.toLowerCase();
    var text;
    if (b === capital[random001]) {
        text = "Correct!";
        hideAndShowDIV();
        execOnEnter = goToNextQuestion;
    } else {
        text = input001.value.bold() + " is not correct!";
    }
    document.getElementById("input001").value = "";
    document.getElementById("answer001").innerHTML = text;
}

function hideAndShowDIV() {
    var x = document.getElementById("userInput");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function goToNextQuestion() {
    document.getElementById("answer001").innerHTML = "";
    random001 = Math.floor(Math.random() * country.length);
    document.getElementById("country").innerHTML = country[random001];
    hideAndShowDIV()
    execOnEnter = submit001;
    document.getElementById("input001").focus();
}
```

```html
<p id="message001">What is the capital of <text id="country"></text>?</p>
<div id="userInput" style="display:block">
    <input type="text" id="input001" autofocus>
</div>
<p id="answer001"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just tried your solution, but it doesn't work. I am probably doing something wrong... I just updated my code snippet, could you please take a look to see what I am missing?

Comment: And how about using a variable for that state? How can I accomplish that? I am still learning Javascript so I am sorry if I am asking something that must be too obvious...

Comment: Please don't update your question with answers, that makes my answer look stupid. I will provide a snippet to demo.

Comment: I understand. I am sorry about that. I will return it to its original state.

Comment: See the snippet I have added with some other improvements. Note that the random pick may result in the same pick twice or more.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

You could check inside the the `submit001()` function to check if the userInput control is hidden and if so, direct go to the `goToNextQuestion`.

Comment: I have no trouble going directly for the goToNextQuestion function. But I wanted to have a small pause between the answers. I want users to be told if their answer was right or wrong, and only after that, if they want to proceed, move to the next question with the Enter key.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could do this. I would recommend not using this approach though, as hitting the enter button to submit is not intuitive. I would recommend adding a 'submit' button. Regardless you could try this:

```js
        
        var country = ["Italy", "Spain", "Portugal", "France"];
        var capital = ["rome", "madrid", "lisbon", "paris"];
        var random001 = Math.floor(Math.random() * country.length);

        document.getElementById("country").innerHTML = country[random001];

        function input001_onKeyDown(e){
          if(e.keyCode === 13){
            submit001();
          } else {
            clearParagraph();
          }
        }

        function submit001() {

            var b = input001.value.toLowerCase();
            document.querySelector("#input001").value = ''
            var text;
            switch (true) {
                case random001 == 0 && b == capital[0]:
                case random001 == 1 && b == capital[1]:
                case random001 == 2 && b == capital[2]:
                case random001 == 3 && b == capital[3]:
                    text = "Correct! " + b + " is the capital of " + country[random001];
                    goToNextQuestion();
                    break;
                default:
                    text = b + " is not correct!";
                    document.getElementById("input001").value = "";
            }
            document.getElementById("answer001").innerHTML = text
        }

        function hideAndShowDIV() {
            var x = document.getElementById("userInput");
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
            }
        }

        function goToNextQuestion() {
            random001 = Math.floor(Math.random() * country.length);
            document.getElementById("country").innerHTML = country[random001];
            document.getElementById("input001").focus();
        }

        function clearParagraph(){
          document.querySelector("#answer001").innerHTML = ''
        }
```

```html
    <p id="message001">What is the capital of <text id="country"></text>?</p>
    <div id="userInput" style="display:block">
        <input type="text" id="input001" autofocus onKeyDown="input001_onKeyDown(event)">
    </div>
    <p id="answer001"></p>
```

Comment: I realized after submitting this doesn't fully answer your "double enter" question. You could have a global (bad idea) boolean that gets flipped to true when they answer the question correctly. Then when they hit enter check if the boolean === true and goToNextQuestion() otherwise run the submit001()

Comment: Thank you for your help. But that is not quite what I was looking for. I want to have an extra step inbetween answers where I can add some trivia about the answer. Hence hiding the input after each correct answer. To make the user slow down a bit before being presented with the next question right away.

Answer (score 0):

Without going into too much detail (I'd have to understand a lot more about the behavior that you would want in various scenarios . . . **Example**: Can the user go back to a previous question, change the answer, and revalidate?), I'd suggest some kind of indicator attached to or associated with (i.e., on a close ancestor element) the input to track whether or not an answer has been validated yet.

For example, you could us a class (e.g., `class="answer-validated"`) or a data attribute (e.g., `data-validated="true"`) if the user has already hit `Enter` to check the value.  In the case of a class, it would be absent by default and the "validation" code would add it as part of its logic.  Similarly, the data attribute could default to "false" and be updated to "true" when the answer is validated.

The benefit of this approach is that it allows you to directly control the tracking of the input state and, potentially reuse it for other functionality, including:

- resetting the input state, if the user wants to re-answer,
- easily resetting the state of *all* questions, without having to refresh/reset the page
- applying visual differences with CSS, based on the presence of the class or state of the data attribute
- track the number of answers that have been checked and place a limit on the maximum number of validations (i.e., "You can only check 3 answers before submitting your answers")
- Etc.

It's possible to infer the state from other elements on the page, but I would argue that it would make more sense to manage the state of the input on itself, rather than determining it based on the state of another page element.  It's more straightforward and less prone to having changes to the other elements impact the functionality of the input.